# DetailsView conditionally enable edit field

Tags: asp.net, roles, detailview

I have an existing asp.net detailsview and the information can be edited by a number of different roles. A new bit field has been introduced (checkbox) and the page is working correctly.

The next step is to limit the editing of this field to only one role. How can I set the edit controls as disabled?

Methods tried are

- Code behind - in the Detailsview's mode change event, the edit controls haven't been rendered, so can't be disabled yet
- In page code - This works enabling and disabling the control. This issue is that the field isn't saving the update. I suspect this is an issue of the code in the template. The code I'm using is:

```html
<EditItemTemplate>
  <% If User.IsInRole("SystemAdministrator") Then%>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="BypassIpLockdownCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ByPassIPLockdown") %>' />
  <% Else%>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ByPassIPLockdown") %>' Enabled="false" />
    <% End If%>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

How can I conditionally enable/disable the field?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="BypassIpLockdownCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ByPassIPLockdown") %>' Enabled='<%# User.IsInRole("SystemAdministrator") %>' />
```

Comment: This won't compile. Getting the message "Server tags cannot contain <%,,,%> constructs".